# js disable radio option on selecting the other

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I got 24 questions with 4 options (a,b,c,d) and user needs to select what fits the most with him and the least. That all works. Now need to create with JS that user cannot select the same answer for most and for least.

So far I tried this code :

```js
function radioChange(radioSet, radioButton, radioArray) {

  if (radioSet.substring(radioSet.length - 1) == "s") {
    radioSet.replace(/\s$/, 'm');
  }
  if (radioSet.substring(radioSet.length - 1) == "m") {
    radioSet.replace(/\m$/, 's');
  }
  if (radioArray[0] == null) {
    radioArray[0] = radioButton;
    document.getElementsByName(radioSet)[0].disabled = true;
  } else {
    radioArray[0] = radioButton;
    document.getElementsByName(radioSet)[0].disabled = false;
  }

}
var radioArray = [null];
```

```html
<!--
this is the html I use : (and tested it just for the first 2 options, but it needs for all the 24 questions)
-->
<div class="dt">
  <div class="dtb">
    <div class="dtr">
      <div class="one">1</div>
      <div class="two">a</div>
      <div class="three"><input name="1m" onclick="radioChange('1m','a',radioArray);" type="radio" value="a" required /></div>
      <div class="four"><input name="1s" onclick="radioChange('1s','a',radioArray);" type="radio" value="a" required /></div>
      <div class="five">Aardig, vriendelijk</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dtr">
      <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="two">b</div>
      <div class="three"><input name="1m" onclick="radioChange('1m','b',radioArray);" type="radio" value="b" required /></div>
      <div class="four"><input name="1s" onclick="radioChange('1s','b',radioArray);" type="radio" value="b" required /></div>
      <div class="five">Overtuigend, overredend</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dtr">
      <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="two">c</div>
      <div class="three"><input name="1m" type="radio" value="c" required /></div>
      <div class="four"><input name="1s" type="radio" value="c" required /></div>
      <div class="five">Terughoudend, bescheiden, gereserveerd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dtr">
      <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="two">d</div>
      <div class="three"><input name="1m" type="radio" value="d" required /></div>
      <div class="four"><input name="1s" type="radio" value="d" required /></div>
      <div class="five">Origineel, inventief, individualistisch</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dt">
  <div class="dtb">
    <div class="dtr">
      <div class="one">2</div>
      <div class="two">a</div>
      <div class="three"><input name="2m" type="radio" value="a" required /></div>
      <div class="four"><input name="2s" type="radio" value="a" required /></div>
      <div class="five">Charmant, attractief, trekt anderen aan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dtr">
      <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="two">b</div>
      <div class="three"><input name="2m" type="radio" value="b" required /></div>
      <div class="four"><input name="2s" type="radio" value="b" required /></div>
      <div class="five">Co&ouml;peratief, aangenaam</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dtr">
      <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="two">c</div>
      <div class="three"><input name="2m" type="radio" value="c" required /></div>
      <div class="four"><input name="2s" type="radio" value="c" required /></div>
      <div class="five">Koppig, onbuigzaam</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dtr">
      <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="two">d</div>
      <div class="three"><input name="2m" type="radio" value="d" required /></div>
      <div class="four"><input name="2s" type="radio" value="d" required /></div>
      <div class="five">Lief, innemend</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It only works on the initial choice, but not when the user changes again, and it needs to disable the input field with the value, since they're all named `1m` for example, but if user selects `1m` value `A`, then `1s` value `A` needs to be disabled, but enabled again when user selects different value from `1m`, and also the other way around, when user selects `1s` value `C` first, it needs to disable `1m` `C`. Also this code is horrible and should be an easier way for this. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful about radio names & values. I've updated your names and values ***optionally*** along with the ***functionality to get the selected values***, see the demonstration below -

```js
function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get all the inputs.
    var inputs = form1.elements;
    var radios = [];

    //Loop and find only the Radios
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'radio') {
            radios.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }

    //var found = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            console.log(radios[i].value);
            //found = 0;
            //break;
        }
    }

    return false; // prevent further bubbling of event
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" onsubmit='handleClick(event)'>
    <div class="dt">
        <div class="dtb">
            <div class="dtr">
                <div class="one">1</div>
                <div class="two">a</div>
                <div class="three"><input name="a" type="radio" value="1m" required /></div>
                <div class="four"><input name="a" type="radio" value="1s" required /></div>
                <div class="five">Aardig, vriendelijk</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dtr">
                <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="two">b</div>
                <div class="three"><input name="b" type="radio" value="1m" required /></div>
                <div class="four"><input name="b" type="radio" value="1s" required /></div>
                <div class="five">Overtuigend, overredend</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dtr">
                <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="two">c</div>
                <div class="three"><input name="c" type="radio" value="1m" required /></div>
                <div class="four"><input name="c" type="radio" value="1s" required /></div>
                <div class="five">Terughoudend, bescheiden, gereserveerd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dtr">
                <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="two">d</div>
                <div class="three"><input name="d" type="radio" value="1m" required /></div>
                <div class="four"><input name="d" type="radio" value="1s" required /></div>
                <div class="five">Origineel, inventief, individualistisch</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dt">
        <div class="dtb">
            <div class="dtr">
                <div class="one">2</div>
                <div class="two">a</div>
                <div class="three"><input name="a2" type="radio" value="2m" required /></div>
                <div class="four"><input name="a2" type="radio" value="2s" required /></div>
                <div class="five">Charmant, attractief, trekt anderen aan</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dtr">
                <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="two">b</div>
                <div class="three"><input name="b2" type="radio" value="2m" required /></div>
                <div class="four"><input name="b2" type="radio" value="2s" required /></div>
                <div class="five">Co&ouml;peratief, aangenaam</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dtr">
                <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="two">c</div>
                <div class="three"><input name="c2" type="radio" value="2m" required /></div>
                <div class="four"><input name="c2" type="radio" value="2s" required /></div>
                <div class="five">Koppig, onbuigzaam</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dtr">
                <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="two">d</div>
                <div class="three"><input name="d2" type="radio" value="2m" required /></div>
                <div class="four"><input name="d2" type="radio" value="2s" required /></div>
                <div class="five">Lief, innemend</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, but the radio button should be selecting 1m A,B,C or D, instead of 1mA or 1sA. Also need with php to know if 1m = A as value, that all works now, but won't work after this.